# Query Native - could not extract ResultSet

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

i have a problem.I explain my situation: SpringBoot + Hibernate + Multitenant (DB master + DB for tenant) + Postgressql. I have two datasource configurations, one for the master and one for each client's database. I need doing a query native in JPARepository And that's the only way I can do it
In my JPARepository :

```
public interface IEntity extends JpaRepository<Entity, Integer> {

    ........

    @Query(value = "ALTER SEQUENCE entity_identity_seq RESTART", nativeQuery = true)
    @Modifying   ///Add 1
    @Transactional  ///Add 2
    void restarID();

}
```

when I first call the method, I got:

```
> Hibernate: 
        ALTER SEQUENCE entity_identity_seq RESTART

> 2019-09-10 15:41:53.919  WARN 18680 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 02000
> 2019-09-10 15:41:53.919 ERROR 18680 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : La consulta no retornó ningún resultado.
> 2019-09-10 15:41:53.940 ERROR 18680 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: La consulta no retornó ningún resultado.
```

After looking for solutions and discovered that he needed to add

```
@Query(value = "ALTER SEQUENCE entity_identity_seq RESTART", nativeQuery = true)
    @Modifying
    void restarID();
```

But the query is not made in hibernate and this error comes up:

```
> 2019-09-10 15:46:57.972 ERROR 14392 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query] with root cause

javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

I keep searching and find that I should add `@Transactional`. Then :

```
   @Query(value = "ALTER SEQUENCE entity_identity_seq RESTART", nativeQuery = true)
        @Modifying
        @Transactional
        void restarID();
```

But, then come back, I call the method, I got:

```
> Hibernate: 
        ALTER SEQUENCE entity_identity_seq RESTART
    > 2019-09-10 15:41:53.919  WARN 18680 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 02000
    > 2019-09-10 15:41:53.919 ERROR 18680 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : La consulta no retornó ningún resultado.
    > 2019-09-10 15:41:53.940 ERROR 18680 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: La consulta no retornó ningún resultado.
```

Please, will anyone have any recommendations? 
I am new to hibernate. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to change the return type to `long`?

Comment: No, but now yes. And it fail. :( @Selindek

Comment: I have no idea what's the return type of your native query, but based on the exception message it's not void. Maybe boolean? What's the result if you run that query directly from a DB-console?

Comment: @Selindek , I have tried with: boolean, Result, Object, new object, etc. And it worked. The query returns as if it were an insert.

Answer (score 0):

If someone yet have the same problem, I've resolved it, adding the next to the query:

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional
```